# Fluid inflow looks like a "shower" - How do I make the inflow more "cohesive"?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm working on a fluid simulation in blender 2.78a. (screenshot of issue below)

Inside of my fluid domain, I have a couple obstacles, an inflow and an outflow. The issue I'm having is that the fluid from the inflow seems to be spraying all over the place. I want the fluid to come in a more "cohesive" fashion, so that it goes into the "cup" more or less. (still have to tweak the inflow velocity).

With the current inflow velocities (y 1, z 1), the some of the fluids enter the cup while the rest misses or splashes off when I have my baking resolution at 67 (or whatever the default is). At that resolution, the fluid inflow was acceptable and relatively "cohesive".

When I increased the baking resolution (to 300), the "showering affect" became to appear.

How do I remove the "showering effect" (as shown in the image below) to make the inflow more cohesive?

Thanks!

[image: The issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two reasons, either the inflow object is the wrong shape or its inverted inside out.

Try to recalculate the normal's or switch to a different shape like a cylinder.

[image]

If you upload your .blend, I can make one with your specific example
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I found the issue when I switched my inflow object to a cylinder. As I mentioned in the question, I had set the inflow to  Y: 1, Z: 1. With the cylinder, I kept the the Z inflow velocity at 1. What I think happened was that the inflow was deflecting off the top of the domain since it had a Z/"upward" inflow velocity. That is why I think the "showering effect" occurred. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Oh, that makes sence, I can see that.